# bash: for loop, two variables linked

Tags: bash, variables, loops, for-loop

I've the following problem; two directories that containing:

- dir1: a list of files like the following:

file1.fq file2.fq file3.fq

and so on..

- dir2: a lis of files like the following:

file1.fq.sa file2.fq.sa file3.fq.sa

what I have to do is running a command that uses file1.fq and file1.fq.sa together.

I've tried the following loop:

```
fq=dir1/*
sa=dir2/*

for fqfiles in $fq;

do

for sa_files in $sa;

do

mycommand ${sa_files} ${fqfiles} > ${sa_files}.cc &

done

done
```

The problem is that my loop execute the following:

```
mycommand file1.fq.sa file1.fq > file1.fq.sa.cc  #correct
```

but also

```
mycommand file1.fq.sa file2.fq > file1.fq.sa.cc  #wrong!
```

and so on...in a almost infinite loop!

I wish my loop could produces something like:

```
mycommand file1.fq.sa file1.fq > file1.fq.sa.cc
mycommand file2.fq.sa file2.fq > file2.fq.sa.cc
mycommand file3.fq.sa file3.fq > file3.fq.sa.cc
```

etc...

Could you please help me?

Thank you!

Fabio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over `dir1`, use [`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) on the files and then prefix with `dir2` and append the extension you need. You might also want to check for the files in the second directory and run your command only if both files are available

```
for f in dir1/*.fq; do
    b=$(basename "$f")
    f2=dir2/"$b".sa
    if test -f "$f2"; then
        mycommand "$f2" "$f" >"$b".sa.cc
    fi
done
```

If you don't want the directory parts, use this one instead

```
mycommand "$b".sa "$b" >"$b".sa.cc
```

Comment: great! It works! Thank you. I will study in the details the basename option!