# Matching two files via a for loop (Bash)

Tags: bash, file, for-loop

I have a series of files in two separate directories that I would like to match with each other.  The nomenclature looks like this:

Forward directory:
    1_A_R1_Paired.gz,
    1_B_R1_Paired.gz,
    2_A_R1_Paired.gz,
    2_B_R1_Paired.gz
    etc

Reverse directory:
    1_A_R2_Paired.gz,
    1_B_R2_Paired.gz,
    2_A_R2_Paired.gz,
    2_B_R2_Paired.gz
etc

I'd like to set up my for loop so that my command is executed only on matching files R1 and R2, so that the outcome would be:

```
my_command 1_A_R1_Paired.gz 1_A_R2_Paired.gz > 1_A_R1R2.bam
```

But not:

```
my_command 1_A_R1_Paired.gz 1_B_R2_Paired.gz > 1_AB_R1R2.bam
```

Someone else had a similar problem here: [bash: for loop, two variables linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087634/bash-for-loop-two-variables-linked). That solution was:

```
for f in dir1/*.fq; do
    b=$(basename "$f")
    f2=dir2/"$b".sa
    if test -f "$f2"; then
        mycommand "$f2" "$f" >"$b".sa.cc
    fi
done
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me, probably because my files don't have the same base name.  Can someone give me a suggestion?  I'm quite the novice here.

Answer (score 0):

If the basename of both files are not an exact match you can change the name of the file you are looking for, for example by using `sed`.

A solution could look like this:

```
for f in dir1/*.qz; do
    b=$(basename "$f")
    f2=`sed s/R1/R2/ <<< "dir2/$b.gz"`
    if test -f "$f2"; then
        mycommand "$f" "$f2" > "$b".sa.cc
    fi
done
```

Note that the `sed` command should be adapted to fit your pattern, now it is simply replacing the first `R1` with `R2`.

Comment: This solution also works, though I'm less certain as to why, since the usage of sed is less clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

To get the pairs, first get the prefix and suffix:

```
for file in *R1*.gz
do
    prefix="${file%R1*}"
    suffix="${file#*R1}"
    if [ -f "${prefix}R2${suffix}" ]
    then
        my_command "${prefix}R1${suffix}" "${prefix}R2${suffix}" > "1_A_R1R2.bam"
    fi
done
```

Comment: This worked great, once I sorted out the fact that I am an idiot.  Thanks!