# Loop upon different files

Tags: loops, unix, for-loop, task

I need to do something like this:

```
command-line FILE1=fwd_common-name FILE2=rev_common-name > output=common-name.new
```

I need to do a task with `Unix` with a program that requires two files, my files have the following names:

`fwd_common-name` and `rev_common-name`

I want an output with `common-name.new`

I tried it:

```
for f1 in ../fwd_* ; do for f2 in ../rev_* ; do command "$f1" "$f2" > `base-name $f1.new` ; done ; done
```

But it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to run your command only on pairs of files with matching `common-name`.  If that is incorrect, the rest of my comment is irrelevant to you and you should disregard it.  :)

Let's call the number of pairs **N**, so you want **N** executions.  This script as written runs **N<sup>2</sup>** executions: all combinations of these files, whether they match or not.  Instead, use a single loop over the `fwd_*` files and specify the `rev_` file's name explicitly to match.

Comment: Here's a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087634/bash-for-loop-two-variables-linked?rq=1

Comment: And another!  Hope these are useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740084/matching-two-files-via-a-for-loop-bash?lq=1

Comment: Thanks broadmonkey,you are right, the problem is that i have a lot unnecessary combinations, but specify the name of one of the couple of files is difficult to me because I'm working with a lot of files...

Comment: Thanks broadmonkey, I looked the links a these were very useful to solve the problem!!! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: I just needed to correct the name of the file 2 using $(echo "$f2" | sed 's/<common-name-1>//g'), when I call it, because always kept the common name for the file 1, I don't know why?